# Which wisdom books are advice of a father to his son?

Tags: catholicism, solomon, catholic-bible, sirach, father

Which of the following wisdom books,

- Proverbs
- Ecclesiastes
- Wisdom
- Ecclesiasticus (Sirach),

are advice addressed by a father to his son?

<sup>Yes, Job, the Psalms, and Solomon's Canticle of Canticles (Song of Solomon) are wisdom literature, too, but they're clearly not father-son advice.</sup>

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question, it's well known that Proverbs was written by Solomon for his son(s). He says "son" something like 40 times. So what's the point of the question?

Comment: @curiousdannii Just Proverbs? Ecclesiastes 12:12 and 18× in Ecclesiasticus (Sirach) address "my son" as well.

Comment: How does my question solicit opinion-based answers?

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting notion and I like this question that you've clearly and concisely answered yourself.  Job,  is definitely not father son advice, but it might have left an impression on his daughters.

Comment: Do you mean to ask which singular wisdom book is this, or which ones plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the wisdom literature (even if only Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, and Ecclesiasticus (Sirach) explicitly address "my son") is father-son instruction; it is

> divided insofar as words work in a twofold way to instruct, in one way, by
>
> 1. **asking for the gift of wisdom**. Wisdom 7:7: ‘Wherefore I have wished, and understanding was given me, and I called upon God, and the spirit of wisdom came upon me.’ This is how the [***Psalter***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/21001.htm) instructs, speaking to God in prayer. In another way,
> 2. by **teaching wisdom**, and this in two ways according to the twofold work of wisdom, one of which is to expose the liar, and [***Job***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/20001.htm) who drove out errors by way of disputation exhibits this. Job 13.3-4: ‘But yet I will speak to the Almighty and I desire to reason with God, having first shown that you are forgers of lies and maintainers of perverse opinions.’ The other work is not to lie about what it knows, and thus we are instructed in a twofold way, because either
> 3. **wisdom is commended to us**, and this in the book of [***Wisdom***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/25001.htm), or
> 4. the **precepts of wisdom are proposed**, and this in the three books of Solomon, which indeed differ according to the three grades of virtue that Plotinus, in Enneads 1.1.2.2-7, distinguishes, since the precepts of wisdom ought to concern only the acts of virtue. In the first grade, according to him, are
>
>    1. **political virtues**, whereby a man moderately uses the things of this world and lives among men, and this in the [***Proverbs***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/22001.htm). In the second grade are the
>    2. **purgative virtues**, whereby a man regards the world with contempt, and this in [***Ecclesiastes***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/23001.htm), which aims at contempt of the world, as is clear from [Jerome’s prologue](https://sites.google.com/site/aquinasstudybible/home/ecclesiastes/jerome-commentary-on-ecclesiastes). In the third grade are the
>    3. **virtues of the purged soul**, whereby a man, wholly cleansed of worldly cares, delights in the contemplation of wisdom alone, and this is found in the [***Song of Songs***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/24001.htm). In the fourth grade are the
>    4. **exemplar virtues existing in God**, concerning which precepts of wisdom are not given but are rather derived from them. In word and in deed [***Sirach***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/26001.htm) instructs. Hence the precepts of wisdom in praise of fathers close his book, as is clear in Chapter 44 and after.
>
> —St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Hic est liber*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Principium.htm#1) pt. 2

[St. Jerome's prologue](https://sites.google.com/site/aquinasstudybible/home/ecclesiastes/jerome-commentary-on-ecclesiastes#_ftnref1) to [his commentary on Ecclesiastes](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7856) says Solomon

> produced an equal number of titles to the three volumes: *Proverbs*, *Ecclesiastes*, and *Song of Songs*. He
>
> 1. **teaches for children** in [***Proverbs***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/22001.htm) and gives instruction in the form of maxims almost with a sense of duty, and his sermons here are repeated continually to his son. In
> 2. [***Ecclesiastes***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/23001.htm) he **teaches a man of mature age** that he should not think anything in the world to be perpetual, but that all things that we perceive are in fact vain and fleeting. In
> 3. [***Song of Songs***](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/24001.htm) he **embraces an elderly man** in the covenant, who has already been prepared in spurning his times.
>
> Philosophers educate their followers in a manner similar to this type of instruction: first of all they teach ethics, then explain physics, and then anyone whom they see to excel in these first two they then go on to teach theology.

Comment: So is Sirach ascribed to Sirach's son or is the scribe of Sirach Sirach's son son?

Comment: @PeterTurner [_A Catholic Commentary on Holy Scripture_](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7785): "§396h Authorship and Date—The data of the Prologue, of 50:29 and 51:1 in Vg, of 50:27 in LXX, and of 50:27 and colophon after ch 51 in Heb. (in the last two of which the name ‘Simeon’ is critically suspect), show that the author’s name was _Yešua‘_ (Gk ‘Jesus’), his father’s name Eleazer, and his grandfather’s Sirach. In Heb. idiom he is often called _Yešua ‘ben Sirach_ ‘Jesus son of Sirach’; or simply Ben Sirach."