# Old Testament verse on how money gives one stability/security?

Tags: old-testament, money, verse-identification

What is the Old Testament verse that says that money gives one stability and security?

I remember reading something along these lines in, I think, [the Wisdom literature](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/78073/1787).

Comment: Did you mean hard work or money because there are many verses that disprove the question.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the book of Proverbs I found three possible verses but instead of the word 'money' the N.I.V. spoke of 'wealth':

> "Lazy hands make a man poor, but diligent hands bring wealth." Prov.
> 10:4
>
> "A man's riches may ransom his life, but a poor man hears no threat."
> Prov. 13:8
>
> "Humility and the fear of the Lord bring wealth and honour and life."
> Prov. 22:4

In the book of Job, Job mentioned gold, security and great wealth (of which he had vast amounts before being afflicted), but he gave a warning about that:

> "If I have put my trust in gold or said to pure gold, 'You are my
> security', if I have rejoiced over my great wealth, the fortune my
> hands have gained...'" then Job said that would be sin to be judged.
> Job 31:24-28

I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Bread is made for laughter, and wine gladdens life, and money answers
> everything. (ESV)
>
> Parties are made for having a good time, wine adds cheer to life, and
> money has an answer for everything. (CJB)
>
> Ecclesiastes 10:19

A good paraphrase of the above is: “Money talks!”

The verse has an ironic interpretation, so don't take this literally!

> The wealth of the rich is their fortified city,
> but poverty is the ruin of the poor. (Proverbs 10:15 NIV)

Comment: "money answers everything" is a strange translation; "all things obey money" ([Douay](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=23&ch=10&l=19#x)) makes more sense.

Comment: Looking in my NIV concordance (Goodrick & Kohlenberger), the word “anah” has four senses. The most common (314 of 413 uses) relates to speech, as answer, answered, replied, said, testify, accuse, etc. The second most common usage (81 times) relates to oppression: afflicted, deny, oppress, subdue, afflict, raped,  violated, force, submit, etc. It is mostly on the side of forcing and the aggressor, not the side of submitting and obeying, the party who obeys.

Comment: The sense seems to be that money commands/rules all things (of the world).